# Send image to server side by javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, screenshot, radeditor

I wrote a code in javascript to paste screenshot in radeditor and now i want to store that image to database some how, so i guess i must send it to server side, but i don't know how. 
Is there any way to see that image in server side?

And this is the code of pasting screenshot in radeditor:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

window.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
 var editor = $find("<%=edtText.ClientID%>")
  editor.get_document().body.onpaste = function(e) {
  var items = e.clipboardData.items;
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
   if (items[i].kind == 'file' &&
    items[i].type.indexOf('image/') !== -1) {

     var blob = items[i].getAsFile();
     window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
     var blobUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

     var editor = $find("<%=edtText.ClientID%>");
     var imageSrc = "<img src='" + blobUrl + "'>";
     editor.pasteHtml(imageSrc);
    }
   }
  }
 });

</script>
```